# Javascript alert и innerHTML

Tags: javascript

Почему в этом скрипте  alert(text) выполняется раньше innerHTML?
и как надо исправить, чтобы alert(text) выполнился позже? Спасибо!

```
 <script language="javascript">
     text = 'text';
     document.getElementById('t1').innerHTML = text;
     document.write(text);
     alert(text);
 </script>
```

Comment: откуда предположение, что alert выполняется раньше?

Comment: Интерпретатор не ждет пока текст появится в DOM'e, а сразу выполняет следующий код.

Comment: `alert` - это [модальное окно](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE). Это значит что пока его не закроют, приложение, породившее это окно работать не будет.